# mint token when supply exceeds 2^64/10*decimals

Tags: mint

how can I mint new token when my supply exceeds 2 ^^ 64 / 10 x decimals tokens?
Or are there any methods to reduce decimals? Help me please

Comment: It appears that you have refined and reposted your question so I’m voting to close this one. [Change existing token's decimal](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/change-existing-tokens-decimal)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, any token mint's maximum supply is 2^64 - 1 since its type is `u64`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new token using the [SPL Token CLI](https://spl.solana.com/token#setup) you can specify the number of decimals using the `--decimals` argument.

```
 % spl-token create-token --decimals 2

Creating token GrnPLdqszDQaYEunJBAW7c8gTmqrcZzqEzFK8F9YGE3e under program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Address:  GrnPLdqszDQaYEunJBAW7c8gTmqrcZzqEzFK8F9YGE3e
Decimals:  2
```

Now you can mint up to $\frac{2^{64} - 1}{2}$ tokens.

```
 % spl-token create-account GrnPLdqszDQaYEunJBAW7c8gTmqrcZzqEzFK8F9YGE3e                                                                                                                   
Creating account B34DJ8ymK9GbRCMMEn1pwobrruCd8ek5KWtWHkmCWxLR

 % spl-token mint GrnPLdqszDQaYEunJBAW7c8gTmqrcZzqEzFK8F9YGE3e 18446744073709551615                                                                                                        
Minting 18446744073709552000 tokens
  Token: GrnPLdqszDQaYEunJBAW7c8gTmqrcZzqEzFK8F9YGE3e
  Recipient: B34DJ8ymK9GbRCMMEn1pwobrruCd8ek5KWtWHkmCWxLR
```

Comment: I mean can I change decimals for existing token? How can I mint them if its supply exceeds 2^64/10*decimals tokens?